# Exclude isotope-hidden items from slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, magnific-popup

Question copied from another user who asked this 7 months ago on github as i have the same problem and no solution found there as well [GitHub Question Link.](http://goo.gl/9Jmxb0)

I have used Magnific-Popup in conjunction with isotope in a wordpress  projects to make a gallery with slideshow and filters. When I filter the items with isotope, it adds the class `isotope-hidden`. But the magnific-popup disregards that class and displays all items also when in slideshow mode.

My popup items are in a div with class `.portfolio-item` I am using the following code for magnific popup

```
 $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            image: {
                titleSrc: 'alt',
                verticalFit: true
            },
            gallery:{
                enabled:true
            }              
        });
```

Comment: have you tried the answer there? adding `delegate: ':not(.isotope-hidden) a.item'`

Comment: yes i did and it doesn't works... i think the reason might be that `.isotope-hidden` is added when we apply filters but magnific popup had already listed the image by then and it stops showing the lightbox entirely.

Comment: can you prepare a jsfiddle with a sample?

Answer (score 2):

try targeting the container of the isotope elements in the magnificPopup initialization, something like this:

```
$('.container').magnificPopup({
    delegate: ':not(.isotope-hidden) a.item',
    type: 'image',
    image: {
        titleSrc: 'alt',
        verticalFit: true
    },
    gallery:{
        enabled:true
    }              
});
```

it this doesn't work what if you use a built in ready solution for this, for example this one: http://codecanyon.net/item/media-boxes-responsive-jquery-grid/5683020 it uses isotopeV2 and Magnific Popup already

Comment: I encountered a similar issue w/TableSorter filtering. I targeted `('#tableID tbody')` and then used the selector `'a.item:visible'` to page through the remaining filtered, visible results.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Reading some of the suggestions here and on GitHub has lead me to try this:

```
delegate: 'li:not(.isotope-hidden).item a'
```

In my context, it worked. Current working experiment is [here](http://www.deadfishchronicles.com/gallery2.php).